# queryActivityStartingFromDate not return actually data

Tags: ios, core-motion

```
func queryActivityStartingFromDate(_ start: NSDate!,
                        toDate end: NSDate!,
                       toQueue queue: NSOperationQueue!,
                   withHandler handler: CMMotionActivityQueryHandler!)
```

the problem is when the end date is now date,for the most of the time I can not get the full activities.Did anything wrong?

Comment: _Cannot get the full activities_, which means there are in fact some? Can you post those along with the dates you pass in?

Comment: there is in fact some, while the last one 's startDate is not so close to my end date.I think there is a delay for this Function.se also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551054/queryactivitystartingfromdate-delay